# Android: When to end class with finish()?

Tags: java, android, class, activity-finish

I often see examples of classes which end with `finish()`, but definitely not always. My question is when should you end a class with `finish()`? And what does it do exactly, what is the difference between ending a class with the back button and ending it with `finish()`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`finish()` can be called to kill (destroy) an Activity instance. If you don't need to close your Activity manual, which is true in many cases, you don't need to call this method.

But if you require a button somewhere in your activity that says "close", then you should use this method. But in general the back button behavior in Android will handle things like this.

The back button does not actually finish your activity, `finish()` calls the `onDestory()` method right away, while the back button does not.

When the back button is pressed, the  `onStop()` method is called, but the `onDestory()` method call might be delayed by the system, this so that the Activity can be resumed by the system which is cheaper (in resources) than a full restart.

Lifecycle:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Finish():
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

You finish `Activity` class with `finish()` method when you need to end the `Activity` immediatly at specific point. If you press back button, you will go through the [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) (`onPause()`, `onStop()` then `onDestroy())` automatically.

Answer (score 2):

One reason to use finish is when you have started the activity with

```
void android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)
```

In this case you dont go back to the Activity which started it with another startActivity but with finish

Answer (score 1):

> public void finish ()
>
> Call this when your activity is done and should be
>   closed. The ActivityResult is propagated back to whoever launched you
>   via onActivityResult().

`finish()` is called to kill your activity instance after you did what you have to do with the activity. After that, you have no use with the activity. So simply call `finish()` and it will kill your activity.

If you press back button, it will call `finish()` automatically to kill the activity. It will go through the activity [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)(`onPause()`, `onStop()` and finally `onDestroy()`)

The one reason with calling finish() is that, if you don't call it, when you navigate through activities, all the activities will be added to the backstack. So when you go back, you have to come back through these activities. So for e.g when you click back button, it simply kills the activity and it will be removed from the backstack.

Answer (score 1):

Back button takes you to the last activity in the stack whereas `finish()` destroys the current activity. You can call `finish()` on an activity for which you don't want the user return to. Example: LoginActivity