# How to get an activity from background avoiding to open a new instance of it

Tags: java, android-studio, android-activity

My app has three **fundamental** activity. Like on Instagram, I have a bottom menu where I can choose one of this activity.

When the app starts the first activity that appears is the **HomeActivity**. So the scheme is like this:

> Home --> Activity 2 --> Activity 3.

After **Activity3** I can choose to go to the **Activity2** or to the Home. 
However, it's important to say that when I start a new activity, the previous one stays in background.
For Example:  when I start the **Activity3**, the **Activity2** is kept in background.

The problem is that, when I go from **Activity3** to **Activity2** 
`like that : Home > Activity 2 > Activity 3 > Activity 2` there will be two different instances of the **Activity2**, one in background and the other running. So the question is:

How can I change my code to make possible that:

If there is no **Activity2** in background, the **Activity3** starts a new **Actvity2** (like It normally does)

If there is an **Activity2** in background, the **Activity3** takes the **Activity2** from background and makes it running (avoiding to open a second instance of the same **Activity2**)

It's hard but I hope I've explained it myself! Thanks for the answers!

Comment: This might help [android-when-to-end-class-with-finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912130/android-when-to-end-class-with-finish)

Comment: Oh, thank you. This post includes some things that I didn't know. That's certainly a way to increase my knowledge. Unfortunately it doesn't contains the answer to my question. Thanks for the try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you launch one `Activity` from another, just add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`, like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will bring the target `Activity` to the front of the task stack (or create a new instance if there is no existing instance in the task stack). The launching `Activity` remains active in the task stack.

In this way you can switch back and forth between your 3 activities and they will just be reshuffled in the task stack.

Comment: Thanks it has been so useful. Flagged as the correct answer