# Getting white screen when trying to open the app. App is getting launched on my phone without errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

When I am trying to run my app on my phone it is getting successfully installed in my phone but I am getting white screen instead of my splash page . Attaching my xml code and java code for your reference . Your help is highly appreciated !!

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:text="MY APP"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

</Relativelayout>
```

activity_main.java

```
package com.example.kriova;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

}

Comment: Finish is the culprit. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912130/android-when-to-end-class-with-finish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The finish() method is called and the activity destroys and returns to the home screen.

Your code should be like this

```
package com.example.kriova;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

}}

Answer (score 0):

remove the last line which is :-
finish();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).